# TFS Dashboard ConcurrencyException

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, tfs

I'm getting an error with the TFS Dashboard Update Job in SharePoint. Is anyone aware of the fix?

```
UpdatedConcurrencyException: The object DashboardUpdateJob Name=Tfs Dashboard Update-82AECAC0-77A8-4e0e-886A-F176B232441C was updated by another user.  Determine if these changes will conflict, resolve any differences, and reapply the second change.  This error may also indicate a programming error caused by obtaining two copies of the same object in a single thread. Previous update information: User: HCA\rrscsvcpasapp Process:OWSTIMER (2448) Machine:RRSCVIRTFS01 Time:March 13, 2015 11:30:57.0000  Current update information: User: HCA\rrscsvcpasapp Process:OWSTIMER (15088) Machine:RRSCVIRTFS01 Time:June 19, 2017 09:00:25.1222   9bb09ab7-3ba8-4803-8f86-b6b4ae278d8f
06/19/2017 09:00:25.13  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x3AF0)                       0x1B04  SharePoint Foundation           Topology                        8xqy    High        ConcurrencyException: Old Version : 209412 New Version : 209412 9bb09ab7-3ba8-4803-8f86-b6b4ae278d8f
06/19/2017 09:00:09.69  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x3AF0)                       0x1B04  TFS Dashboards                  TFS Dashboards                  0000    Exception     Exception Message: An update conflict has occurred, and you must re-try this action. The object DashboardUpdateJob Name=Tfs Dashboard Update-82AECAC0-77A8-4e0e-886A-F176B232441C was updated by HCA\rrscsvcpasapp, in the OWSTIMER (2448) process, on machine RRSCVIRTFS01.  View the tracing log for more information about the conflict. (type SPUpdatedConcurrencyException)  Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPConfigurationDatabase.StoreObject(SPPersistedObject obj, Boolean storeClassIfNecessary, Boolean ensure)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPConfigurationDatabase.Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.ISPPersistedStoreProvider.PutObject(SPPersistedObject persistedObject, Boolean ensure)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPersistedObject.BaseU 4822fc79-6b4a-41ff-acb0-7ef0e1860c3e
06/19/2017 09:00:09.69  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x3AF0)                       0x1B04  TFS Dashboards                  TFS Dashboards                  0000    Exception   pdate()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPJobDefinition.Update()     at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SharePoint.Dashboards.TimerJob.DashboardUpdateJob.Execute(Guid targetInstanceId)    4822fc79-6b4a-41ff-acb0-7ef0e1860c3e
06/19/2017 09:00:25.13  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x3AF0)                       0x1B04  SharePoint Foundation           Timer                           6398    Critical    The Execute method of job definition Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SharePoint.Dashboards.TimerJob.DashboardUpdateJob (ID ea9799e8-1619-47d1-adf1-682c24dbad9e) threw an exception. More information is included below.  An exception occurred while scanning dashboard sites. Please see the SharePoint log for detailed exceptions. 9bb09ab7-3ba8-4803-8f86-b6b4ae278d8f
06/19/2017 09:00:25.13  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x3AF0)                       0x1B04  SharePoint Foundation           Timer                           72ae    Unexpected  Exception stack trace:    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SharePoint.Dashboards.TimerJob.DashboardUpdateJob.Execute(Guid targetInstanceId)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPTimerJobInvokeInternal.Invoke(SPJobDefinition jd, Guid targetInstanceId, Boolean isTimerService, Int32& result) 9bb09ab7-3ba8-4803-8f86-b6b4ae278d8f
06/19/2017 09:00:25.13  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x3AF0)                       0x1B04  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (Timer Job Tfs Dashboard Update-82AECAC0-77A8-4e0e-886A-F176B232441C). Execution Time=47.166050569274   9bb09ab7-3ba8-4803-8f86-b6b4ae278d8f
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UpdatedConcurrencyException` has been previously received suggested fixes by clearing the SharePoint's configuration cache. To clear the configuration cache, do the following:

1. Stop the SharePoint Timer service
2. Go to %SystemDrive%\ProgramData\Microsoft\SharePoint\Config\
3. Take a copy of the `cache.ini` file and move the copy to elsewhere
4. For each XML-file in the `\<GUID<>` folders, delete them. Also if any XMLTEMP-files exist, delete them
5. Open the `cache.ini` with a Notepad
6. Replace the number in the file with `1`, and save
7. Start the SharePoint Timer Service

Each of the steps need to be done on every server part of the farm if you are running a multi-server environment. For more detailed steps, see e.g. [this](http://www.jeremytaylor.net/2013/10/12/clear-sharepoint-cache/).

Comment: There is no cache.ini file in the %SystemDrive%\ProgramData\Microsoft\SharePoint\Config\ folder. But there is a cache.ini file in each of the %SystemDrive%\ProgramData\Microsoft\SharePoint\Config\<GUID> folder. Do I do the same thing?

Comment: @KyleJohnson Yep - correct. Sorry had it wrong in the answer. Will fix it.